# Capturar o momento em que a tela do celular foi acesa e quando foi apagada

Tags: java, android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver

Olá !
   Estou construindo projeto semelhante a um despertador porém estou com algumas dificuldades ao tentar usar a classe broadcastreceiver.
Problema:
    Quero capturar a data e a hora exata que a tela do celular foi acesa, ou seja, se o usuário apenas apertar o botão pra acender a tela e ver se tem notificação, gostaria de capturar esse momento para posteriormente inserir no banco de dados. Do mesmo modo também quero capturar o momento em que a tela é apagada, seguindo praticamente a mesma ideia em relação a tela ser ligada, ao ser apagada quero pegar a hora do sistema para posterioemente salvar no banco de dados.

Mas até o momento consegui usar o broadcastReceiver apenas para fazer o celular vibrar, no exemplo abaixo eu estou tentando ligar e desbloquear a tela, o que eu quero mesmo é capturar esse momento direto do usuário, mas não estou conseguindo nem saber por onde começar:

BroadcastActivity

```
public class MyBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //EXEMPLO PARA FAZER O CELULAR VIBRAR
    /*Toast.makeText(context, "Não entre em panico amigo!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    //Vibrando o celular
    Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
    vibrator.vibrate(2000);*/

    //EXEMPLO PARA FAZER A TELA SER LIGADA E DESTRAVADA
    Intent intentTela = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);
    intentTela.putExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_LIGAR_E_DESTRAVAR_TELA, true);
    context.startActivity(intentTela);

}
}
```

Tela de exemplo:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//ATRIBUTOS
EditText etTime;
Button btOk;
public static final String EXTRA_LIGAR_E_DESTRAVAR_TELA = ChamadaActivity.class.getPackage().getName() + ".LIGAR_E_DESTRAVAR_TELA";


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (true == getIntent().getBooleanExtra(EXTRA_LIGAR_E_DESTRAVAR_TELA, false)){
        //Combinando duas flags
        getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
    }

}

public void configAlarm(View view){
    etTime = findViewById(R.id.time);
    int tempo = Integer.parseInt(etTime.getText().toString());

    Intent intent = new Intent(this, MyBroadcastReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this.getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + (tempo * 1000), pendingIntent);

    Toast.makeText(this, "Alarm marcado para " + tempo + " segundos", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


}
}
```

xml main:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/time"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="number"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
    android:text="Button"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/time"
    android:onClick="configAlarm"/>
   </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <receiver
        android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INPUT_METHOD_CHANGED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <activity android:name=".ChamadaActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Agradeço pela atenção!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deverá criar e registar um BroadcastReceiver que escute os eventos `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF` e `Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON`.

Exemplo:

```
public class ScreenOnOffReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {


        if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)) {

            //A tela foi apagada

        } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)) {

            //A tela foi acesa

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: alterei o código conforme você mencionou mas desculpe bela ignorancia mas agora não sei como chamar a classe broadcast, do jeito que ficou ele simplesmente não faz nada, não poderia me dar um exemplo da activity + a chamada do broadcast quando a tela for ligada ou desligada chamadando a classe vibrator por exemplo? Ou algum site aonde eu possa encontrar mais informações para me ajudar a me virar melhor ?

Comment: https://androidexample.com/Screen_Wake_Sleep_Event_Listner_Service_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=91#

Answer (score 0):

Agradeço muito pela ajuda, e finalmente consegui o que queria, capturar o evento de SCREEN_ON e SCREEN_OFF e por isso gostaria de compartilhar o código completo para que possa ajudar outras pessoas que precisem, segue código complete de um app que vibrará ao capturar ambos os eventos:
No Manifest adicione as seguintes permissões:
AndroidManifest.xml

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
```

e no final da TAG application após a tag activity que receberá os eventos adione o seguinte código:

```
<service android:name="com.nomedopacote.LockService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

segue código das Activitys:
MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    //starting the service Class
    startService(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LockService.class));

}
}
```

Na classe Service que chamará o broadcast

LockService.class

```
public class LockService extends Service {

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    final IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF);
    filter.addAction(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT);

    //Calling the BroadCast
    final BroadcastReceiver mReceiver = new ScreenReceiver();
    registerReceiver(mReceiver, filter);

    return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
}

//AINDA NÃO SEI PARA QUE SERVE
public class LocalBinder extends Binder{
    LockService getService(){
        return LockService.this;
    }
}

}
```

ScreenReceiver.class - onde a magica rola

```
public class ScreenReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

public static boolean wasScreenOn = true;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.e("test", "onReceive Broadcast");

    SimpleDateFormat Dformat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy-HH:mm:ss");
    Date date = new Date();

    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTime(date);
    Date data_atual = cal.getTime();
    String sysdate  = Dformat.format(data_atual);

    //Validating screen status
    if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_OFF)){
        //Vibrate test
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(500);

        wasScreenOn = false;
        Log.e("hora OFF", sysdate);

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_SCREEN_ON)){
        //Vibrate test
        Vibrator vibrator = (Vibrator) context.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
        vibrator.vibrate(1000);

        wasScreenOn = true;
        Log.e("hora ON", sysdate);

    } else if (intent.getAction().equals(Intent.ACTION_USER_PRESENT)){
        Toast.makeText(context, "USER PRESENT", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
}
```

O código inspirador foi retirado do seguinte link: http://usefulcodeforandroid.blogspot.com.br/2013/07/detect-android-actionscreenoff.html
Agradeço a comunidade StackOverflow pela ajuda!